# Using C# console application copy row from sqlite to an excel

Tags: c#, excel, sqlite

In console application i want to copy a row from sqlite into a an excel sheet .I am able to connect to sqlite using below code

```
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = C:\foo;Version=3;");
        connection.Open();
```

Now through which sql command i should get the row and copy to the excel sheet which should be save in unicode.

And how to copy to the excel sheet? 
Please advise

Comment: This could be helpful to you to get an [idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752121/can-i-import-into-excel-from-a-data-source-without-iteration) You can dumb data without iteration.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd look up some documentation on `SQLiteConnection`.  google can help you with this.

You'll probably be able to write a query and iterate over the results.

Next, look up information on Excel Spreadsheet format, or .net excel libraries.   Google can help you with this.

when you iterate over you query results you can load that into an excel spreadsheet.

If you just need something that can be loaded into the Excell application, you can look at the `.csv` format.  Just make a simple sample excell spreadsheet in excell and save it as a `.csv`, and open that in notepad.  the formatting should be pretty easy to interpret from that.